# UWP Contacts, Contact Lists and Contact Timelines

Tags: uwp, contacts, timeline, contact-list

I have found good information from the UWP sample repo on GitHub for how to create contacts for a UWP app as well as contact list annotations.

What I can't find is how I can add line items to the contact's timeline in the same way that the mail program adds recently received emails for that contact or Skype Preview adds recently received calls or messages.

Also, how do you make a contact list readonly to the user? I want the contact list to be updated only by the app. I'm referring to a contact list that is added to the People app. These contacts can then be linked w/ other contacts in the people hub.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re referring to the data that shows up in the timeline it’s actually a number of different sources (both local and cloud-hosted), there’s no specific API that helps process the data, it’s just the combination of [call history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls), [messaging history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.chat), [email history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Email), [calendar data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appointments), and some cloud providers.

The UI is just an extension of the grouped [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview) using the [SemanticZoom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.semanticzoom) control.  Each time span is just a grouping.

> how do you make a contact list readonly to the user? I want the contact list to be updated only by the app.

I'm not sure what you said. If you just get all contacts and show them in a list control, the users should not be able to edit it in your app. If you meant that user updates the contact in People app, then you don't want this operation. I'm afraid you cannot control it. The People app is system default app, it should have access to update the contacts.

Comment: By contact list, I'm referring to a contact list that is added to the People hub/app.

How then do those different sources get their information into a contact's timeline in the people app?

Comment: `How then do those different sources get their information into a contact's timeline in the people app?` For example, you could register a background task with [ChatMessageReceivedNotificationTrigger](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/CommunicationBlockAndFilter/cs/Tasks/MessageReceivedTask.cs#L50), when a new message received, you could add it into different contact's timeline by filtering [ChatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.chat.chatmessage)'s property.

Comment: Xavier, I do appreciate your help, but when you say, I "could add it into different contact's timeline(s)", I'm asking what API is used to do that adding? Not what mechanism I could create to manage when or from what sources. I did find https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Social-Samples and this seems to have an answer to my question. As soon as I get it working, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @DanielPrzybylski There's no specific API to add. You would need to use ListView to make it look like contact timeline in your app. Then when you get a new message, you could add this message into ListView. I believe you know how to dynamically add itme into itemsource and show it on ListView.